# multiplication date by minutes in bash

Tags: shell

i have to multiply day by one day minutes

for example today date 2014/08/04

date=4

totalNumberOfminutesPerDay=1440

4*1440

```
        variable=$(date +"%Y.%m.$((%d*1440))");
```

this gives me this error

```
      -bash: %d*1440: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%d*1440")
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Something like this returns a thing, but not sure if it is expected one: `date +"%Y.%m.$(( $(date "+%d") *1440))"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variable=$(date '+%Y.%m.')$(( $(date '+%e') * 1440 ))
```

Using `+%d` would fail:

```
$ (( $(date -d 2014-08-08 '+%d') * 1440 ))
bash: ((: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the point of keeping saying that the other answer is wrong and asking the OP to go to this. Instead, you could suggest the improvements to the other. I think it is best to collaborate rather than compete.

Comment: @fedorqui It could be in a sense that our answers weren't made at the same time. But nevermind this anyway :) I deleted the comment. Also, collaboration is an option.

Comment: @konsolebox i didnt get what was the problem with %d and how did %e solve it.. i mean in what way was 08 harming

Comment: @user310685 In bash arithmetic, a number starting with 0 is considered octal. `08` is not a valid octal number. More info about octal numbers [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). `%e` doesn't add an extra 0 on it; just a space.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do the multiplication in date's format string.
You have to do a seperate calculation as fedorqui mentioned in his comment:

```
variable=$(date +"%Y.%m.$(( $(date +%e)*1440))");
```

If you want "variable" to be 5760, the following statement is sufficient.

```
variable=$(( $(date +%e)*1440));
```

Comment: This would fail if day > 7. See my answer which solves the issue of oct.

Comment: @konsolebox: can you explain that?